# How to stop a command block that is constantly killing me

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing minecraft with my brother and his friend. The friend placed command blocks that `@kill` players infinitely; is there a way to stop this happening? I have tried the `commandblockoutput` command but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you an OP on the server?

Comment: I feel like this is a dupe...

Comment: @ydobonebi If we're going to dupe something, let's at least try to dupe to something that *isn't* closed.

Comment: Is it possible that setting it to creative mode will stop the dying? Giving you time to change it.

Answer (score 4):

If you know where the command block is (the coordinate) you can do the command `/setblock x y z air`. X, Y, and Z are the coordinates of the command block.

If you have access to World Edit, get as close as you can to the command block, and do `//sphere [number] water`. Replace `[number]` with the distance (it does not have to be exact) to the command block.

If you don't have access to World Edit, and don't know the coordinate of the command block, you can make a huge area filled with air, by doing the command `/fill x y z x y z air`. Replace the first X, Y, and Zs with a estimation of where the command block is, and the second ones with an estimation of the command block is in the other direction. Try to make a square with these coordinates, with the command block in the middle.

Comment: How can he run commands when he keeps getting killed? @AP Coding

Comment: @Nick I think this answer is assuming that OP has access to the server console

Comment: Ah, I see... Thanks for letting me know! I just assumed he was on LAN! @ imulsion

Comment: @Nick That's actually a good point - I forgot that you could play on LAN. To be honest OP probably needs to clarify the question somewhat before it can be answered accurately

Comment: @imulsion I agree!

Comment: @imulsion Also, since OP says that they tried the "`commandblockoutput`" command, I assume they can somehow execute commands, even if it's pasting and slamming enter.

Comment: If its on a server, go into server properties and disable command blocks

Answer (score 2):

This is a little out of your way probably, because it takes more work than the reward possibly, but you could download a basic Minecraft server off of the website ([Minecraft.net](http://www.minecraft.net)). Place the jar in a folder and run the jar. Accept the eula in the eula.txt when it appears. Then, drag your work from MC to the server folder and open server.properties with notepad. In there, change 'world=' to the name of your world. Run the server and connect (You can just use private ipv4 or ipv6 IP). If all goes well, the server.properties should have disabled command blocks, so it cannot run anymore. If not, go into server.properties and turn off command blocks. When you have broken it, close the server with /stop in the console and drag the world back to Minecraft!

Sorry it is kind of difficult, there is probably a better way!

-Nick